# Acute angle between plane and line

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Find the acute angle between:
$x-y-3z=5$
and

$x=2-t$

$y=2t$

$z=3t-1$

Here is how I proceed. I take the dot-product of the normal of the plane and the directional vector of the line. This gives me -12. Now, I use the other form of the equation of the dot-product (u.v=norm of u times norm of v times cos theta).
I equate -12 to the norm of the directional vector times the norm of the normal times the cosine of the angle theta.

I isolate theta to get 165°.
But, I substract 90° to get the acute angle. FINAL ANSWER: 75°.

Can someone check my answer?

Comment: $75^\circ$ is the angle between **normal vector of plane** and the line; subtract it from 90 for the angle between **plane** and the line

Comment: Hi, are you sure?

Comment: 165° is the angle between the normal and the line. There is 90°difference between the normal and the plane. If I substract 90° from the 165°, I get 75°.

Comment: Oh I see... you're right, $165-90$ gives the angle between plane and line! my mistake sorry -.-

Comment: So my answer is 100% right? Please mention your education level :P

Comment: yup :) in general the formula is $\theta = \arcsin\left(\dfrac{n.a}{|n||a|}\right)$ lets ask wolfram also :  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%28-12%2F%28sqrt%2811%29*sqrt%2814%29%29%29*180%2Fpi

Comment: Ok I'll trust you. I hope we both know our stuff. I'm just a first year undergrad :S